# About backslash

Tags: errors, languages

I use my Korean Laptop to type Latex, but When I type a backslash, it shows ₩(Korean dollar).
I can use backslash everywhere but latex. Can you solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  My guess is it will depend on what program you're using to edit TeX files.  And maybe which operating system.

Comment: The issue you describe is not related directly to LaTeX. Instead, it's related to (a) the editor you use to edit your LaTeX document and (b) the operating system on your computer. Please tell us which operating system and which editing program you employ.